# What does the FD column of pipes listed by lsof mean?

Tags: linux, shell, command, file-descriptor, lsof

I'm using the following command to get a list of pipes:

```
lsof | grep PIPE
```

I want to know what the values of the FD column mean (the 5th one https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkjCn.png). I think that `r` and `w` mean **read** and **write**, respectively, but what does the number which follows each of these chars means?

---

I know that FD means File Descriptor, what I want to figure out is what means the values shown in the column, like the 3r, 16w, 20r, etc.

Comment: Reading right now, I've found that w and r really means write and read. But I still don't know what the number means.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Files are not only opened as streams. Some of those are listed in `lsof`'s manual:

```
FD    is the File Descriptor number of the file or:

           cwd  current working directory;
           Lnn  library references (AIX);
           err  FD information error (see NAME column);
           jld  jail directory (FreeBSD);
           ltx  shared library text (code and data);
           Mxx  hex memory-mapped type number xx.
           m86  DOS Merge mapped file;
           mem  memory-mapped file;
           mmap memory-mapped device;
           pd   parent directory;
           rtd  root directory;
           tr   kernel trace file (OpenBSD);
           txt  program text (code and data);
           v86  VP/ix mapped file;

      FD  is  followed  by one of these characters, describing the
      mode under which the file is open:

           r for read access;
           w for write access;
           u for read and write access;
           space if mode unknown and no lock
            character follows;
           '-' if mode unknown and lock
            character follows.

      The mode character is followed by one of these lock  charac-
      ters, describing the type of lock applied to the file:

           N for a Solaris NFS lock of unknown type;
           r for read lock on part of the file;
           R for a read lock on the entire file;
           w for a write lock on part of the file;
           W for a write lock on the entire file;
           u for a read and write lock of any length;
           U for a lock of unknown type;
           x  for an SCO OpenServer Xenix lock on part  of the
      file;
           X for an SCO OpenServer Xenix lock on  the   entire
      file;
           space if there is no lock.

      See  the  LOCKS  section  for  more  information on the lock
      information character.

      The FD column contents constitutes a single field for  pars-
      ing in post-processing scripts.
```

Comment: useless answer/

Answer (score 1):

That is *file descriptor*.

More on it:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

*File descriptor* (FD) is an abstract indicator for accessing a file. The term is generally used in POSIX operating systems.

In POSIX, a file descriptor is an integer, specifically of the C type int. There are three standard POSIX file descriptors, corresponding to the three standard streams, which presumably every process (save perhaps a daemon) should expect to have.

Comment: Sorry Igor, maybe I did not expressed myself correctly. I knew that the FD means File Descriptor, but I want to know exactly what the number and the char means. In the wiki it's shown that 0, 1 and 2 are stdin, stdout and stderr, but, what about a 16r?

Comment: `r` means read access, that mean that file was open in *readonly* mode, and 16 is just a number of the descriptor. It has no special meaning. You can access the file at `/proc/PID/fd/FD` where PID and FD are pid of the process and number of the descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

A file descriptor is a number that uniquely identifies an open file in a computer's operating system. It describes a data resource, and how that resource may be accessed. This max limit for this field specified in the kernel and can be changed to prevent [choking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#file-max-file-nr) (in case the file descriptor limit is reached).